# Remove filenames from Textfile with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to delete filenames from a textfile to have as output only the folder.
Example:

```
Creature\FrostwolfPup\FrostWolfPup_Shadow.m2
Creature\FrostwolfPup\FrostWolfPup_Fire.m2
```

To

```
Creature\FrostwolfPup\
```

To match only the Filenames i use `[^\\]*$`
Now i put it together with sed while `/d` should delete it

```
D:\filetype\core\sed.exe -n -e "/^[^\\]*$/d" D:\filetype\listfile\archive\tmp\all.txt > D:\filetype\module\model_bruteforce\tmp\folders_tmp1.txt
```

But instead of a textfile with my folders i got only a empty textfile as output, and so something must be wrong.

Comment: There are no folders in UNIX, ITYM directories. Also file/directory paths are separated by forward slashes (`directoryA/directoryB/file`), not backslashes (`directoryA\directoryB\file`). Backslashes are valid characters in directory and/or file names while forward slashes are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on linux, not cygwin

```
sed  -r 's/[^\\]*$//g' /path/to/original/file > /path/to/new/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 sed.exe -e "s/[^\\]*$//" path/to/folders.txt
```

The command `s/[^\\]*$//` asks sed to remove everything after the last `\` on a line to the end of the line.

Caveat: since I don't have a windows machine handy for testing, I am unsure if the backslashes need to be doubled as shown above.

#### Discussion

`-n` tells sed not print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.  The following command never asks sed to print:

```
sed.exe -n -e "/^[^\\]*$/d"
```

Consequently, it produces no output.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I tested it, in that specific case also on Windows it seems that double slashes are not necessary in that case, both variants will produce the same output.